# Is there a way to trigger Kafka Connector rebalancing within a Source Task programatically

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, rebalancing

Is it possible to trigger Kafka Connector rebalancing from within the Source Task. The task can detect some exceptional conditions which may warrant the connector to rebalance. The SourceTaskContext does not have a method for rebalancing like requestTaskReconfiguration which SourceConnectorContext does have.

I need to trigger the rebalance within the tasks and not the connector.